# Allow users to customise default import file in package

Tags: python

I have created a package and uploaded it to pypi.

I have created files such as as the following in the package

```
from package.scenario import a

def add(b):
    return a+b
```

And

```
from package.scenario import c
def multiply(b):
    return c*b
```

I have set a number of defaults in the module `package.scenario`, but I would like users to be able to adjust them to their own preferred values.

There are many different files in this package and so it gets complicated if I want to move away from a single importable module. However, I am open to any suggestions.

I would prefer if they didn't have to adjust the code inside the actual package, and rather, create their own file and have that be used instead of the default.

Comment: "I have set a number of defaults..." Default whats? Hard to tell what the end-goal is here.

Comment: Defaults in this example being ```a``` and ```c```. The end goal is to change ```a``` and ```c``` globally in the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with the following code:

```
import sys
import new_package
sys.modules['package'].scenario=new_package
```